# fetchrequest error

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am looping and in each loop I call a function do the following

it crach after second or third iteration at the execution of fetch

any suggestion to solve that

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                                       entityForName:@"Seriese" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                @"( SeriesesStudy.StudiesStudent.StudentID == %@ ) AND ( SeriesesStudy.study_uid == %@ ) AND ( Series_uid == %@ )",self.StudentID,self.study_uid,self.Series_uid  ]];

if (self.managedObjectContext != nil) {
    SeriesList = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]; // crash here
    seriesobject = [SeriesList objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: What does the crash report tell you?

Comment: it give and raise BAD_EXC_ACCESS

Comment: and how are you setting the 'error' parameter?

Comment: Nserror* error; I forget to put it in my question

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the way you set the fetch up so the most likely cause of the crash is that during one loop you pass a bad value for one of the variables that go into the predicate and that causes the predicate to crash upon execution.

BTW, You should change the order of variables in your predicate. Compound predicates execute right to left and you want the simplest (and therefore fastest test) first. Right now, you have the most computationally intensive test first and the simplest last. Change it to:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"( Series_uid == %@ ) AND  ( SeriesesStudy.study_uid == %@  AND ( SeriesesStudy.StudiesStudent.StudentID == %@ )",self.Series_uid,self.study_uid,self.StudentID]
```

... and it will run much faster because it will find all the `Seriese` objects that have a matching `Series_uid` attribute and then use that limited set to perform the relationship walking test upon. Predicate test that cross relationships are many times slower than simple attribute test so they should always be done last.

Comment: the problem is that I release the fetchrequest , after commented it , every thing worked well

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that I release the fetchrequest , after commented it , every thing worked wel